# Does Travis CI export an environment variable containing the GitHub user name?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I'd like to get the GitHub user / organization name within my `.travis.yml` file. That is, if my repository containing the `.travis.yml` is at https://github.com/sschuberth/karn, I'd like to get `sschuberth` at build time. From looking at the [docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/) it seems there's not such variable yet, or am I missing something?

I know I could extract that information from Git's remote URL, but I wanted to have something cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [docs you linked above](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables), there is `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG` which will be your github username/repo, e.g. `sschuberth/karn`, should be quite easy to pick out the username from it.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed missed that as I was searching that page for "user", not "owner"! Doh.

Comment: BTW, the way I'm extracting the user now simply is `$(dirname $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG)`.